# Pandas groupby transform

Tags: python, pandas

Need a confirmation regarding behaviors of Pandas Groupby transform:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                      'foo', 'bar'],
               'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                      'two', 'two'],
               'C' : [1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5],
               'D' : [2.0, 5., 8., 1., 2., 9.]})
grouped = df.groupby('A')
grouped.transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())

          C         D
0 -1.154701 -0.577350
1  0.577350  0.000000
2  0.577350  1.154701
3 -1.154701 -1.000000
4  0.577350 -0.577350
5  0.577350  1.000000
```

It does not specify which column to apply the lambda function. how pandas decide which columns (in this case, C and D) to apply the function? why did it not apply to column B and throw an error?

why the output does not include column A and B?

Comment: Because your operation is arithmetic pandas will only apply it to numeric columns. I suspect in the future pandas may require you to be more explicit, or ensure that all the non grouped columns can be applied on by the callable

Comment: Running the code myself, I get a warning that should be helpful: `FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.transform is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .transform, select only columns which should be valid for the function.`

Comment: I was using pandas 0.25.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupBy.transform` calls the specified function for each column in each group (so `B`, `C`, and `D` - not `A` because that's what you're grouping by). However, the functions you're calling (`mean` and `std`) only work with numeric values, so Pandas skips the column if it's `dtype` is not numeric. String columns are of `dtype` `object`, which isn't numeric, so `B` gets dropped, and you're left with `C` and `D`.

You should have got warning when you ran your code—

```
FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.transform is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .transform, select only columns which should be valid for the transforming function.
```

As it indicates, you need to select the columns you want to process prior to processing in order to evade the warning. You can do that by added `[['C', 'D']]` (to select, for example, your `C` and `D` columns) before you call `transform`:

```
grouped[['C', 'D']].transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ important
```